MatLab error "Undefined function 'linprog' for input arguments of type 'double'"
since a couple of days I am encountering a weird problem:
on macOS Ventura, independent of the matlab version (I have tried 2022_a - 2024_a) I am getting the error mentioned above when running a script. When running the same script in the matlab online version this doesn't happen. Also colleagues with the newest version are able to run the script without problems.
Sidenote: I recently downgraded from macOS Sonoma to Ventura for battery life reasons. Ventura itself cannot be the actual problem though.
Here the script:
model=readCbModel('e_coli_core.mat');

model=convertToIrreversible(model);

FBA=optimizeCbModel(model);

function W = WeightFromGPR(model, reactionID);
    % Get the corresponding GPR rule
    gprRule = model.grRules{reactionID};
    if isempty(gprRule);
        W = 0;
        return;
    elseif ~contains(gprRule, 'and')
        W = 1;
        return;
    else
        % Split GPR rule based on 'or'
        ORgenes = strsplit(gprRule, ' or ');
        
        % Initialize array to store the number of ANDgenes for each ORgene
        numANDgenes = zeros(1, length(ORgenes));
        
        % Iterate over each ORgene
        for i = 1:length(ORgenes)
            % Split GPR rule based on 'and'
            ANDgenes = strsplit(ORgenes{i}, 'and');
            
            % Store the number of ANDgenes for the current ORgene
            numANDgenes(i) = length(ANDgenes);
        end
        
        % Find the smallest number of ANDgenes among all ORgenes
        W = min(numANDgenes);
        return;
    end
end

weights = zeros(size(model.S, 2),1);

for i = 1:size(model.S, 2)
    weights(i) = WeightFromGPR(model, i);
end
model.ub(13)=FBA.f;
model.lb(13)=FBA.f;

%model.osenseStr='min';
l2= optimizeCbModel(model)
[x,fval] = linprog(weights,[],[],model.S,model.b,model.lb,model.ub);

FBAtotalflux = sum(FBA.x);
pFBAtotalfulx = sum(x);




As mentioned before I already tried older versions of matlab 


